# SQL data within the last year

Tags: php, sql, pear, vtiger

I have created a query which seems to execute with no errors. I am getting the total of two columns in two different fields related to one customer, I only want to retrieve the data which was within the past year.

I have used this but it seems to throw all the data stored.

```
$yearago = (date('Y')-1).date('-m-d');
$sumtotal = $adb->pquery("SELECT 
                            SUM(currentamount),
                            SUM(newcurrentamount),
                            (SUM(currentamount) + SUM(newcurrentamount)) as 'Total'
                        FROM vtiger_addisa, vtiger_isa
                        WHERE vtiger_addisa.addrelatedclient = $relatedclient
                        AND vtiger_isa.relatedclient = $relatedclient
                        AND vtiger_isa.startdate >= $yearago
                        ");


$sumtotal->fetchInto($row);
$clientotal = $row['Total'];
echo $clientotal;
//print_r($sumtotal);
```

Comment: Is there a date column in `vtiger_addisa`?

Comment: If there is, you need to check that in the `WHERE` clause, just like you do `vtiger_isa.startdate`.

Comment: BTW, you can use date functions in MySQL: `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` will return the date 1 year ago.

Comment: @Barmar, yes there was a WHERE for vtiger_addisa.date but I had taken it out while trying to debug. After replacing `$yearago` with `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` we are working fine! Not sure why as I had outputted $yearago just fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: You didn't quote `$yearago` that's why it wasn't working. As well it would have failed on leap years.

Comment: Since you didn't quote the date, it was treating `2016-04-14` as a numerical calculation, so your code was equivalent to `vtiger_isa.startdate > 1998`.